# How to add kostaskougios/cloning library to Intelij project ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to add [this](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning) library to my Intelij project. I have downloaded the whole repository as .zip format from the github. I have tried to add the .zip file using ".jar or directories" and "library" option. I have also extracted the .zip file and try to add by the ".jar or directories" option. But in both way it does not works. It says `empty library`. How to add this library to my intelij project. I am using Intelij Ultimate 14.1.4.
Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the zip in the libs folder of your project then right click and select "add as library."

This has already been answered here: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But there is no folder like `libs` in my project library. For your information,  I have tried to add google guava library that is in `.jar` works well. But when i download the project from the github as a .zip file format and try to add to intelij then it does not work.

Comment: That's weird, they're usually treated the same way. Have you tried the other solutions in the question I posted a link to? @seal

Comment: I got the solution. .zip file contain no `.class` file that i have downloaded from github. Therefore i need to build the project first.